# Iniciar aplicação Node no boot Linux (Raspberry)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Boa tarde a todos,

Tenho uma aplicação JS que precisa ser iniciada no boot Linux, como poderia iniciar essa aplicação? Tentei com systemd, mais não funcionou. Vocês poderiam me passar algum link ou dica? Algum erro no arquivo abaixo?

gerente.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gerente
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/eu/projetos/node/socket5/npm start
RuntimeDirectory=socket5
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[Unit]
Description=Gerente
After=syslog.target
```

Execução:

```
root@raspberry:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl start gerente.service
Job for gerente.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status gerente.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@raspberry:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status gerente.service
● gerente.service - Gerente
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gerente.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-07 16:48:20 -02; 27s ago
  Process: 1397 ExecStart=/home/harley/projetos/node/socket5/npm start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1397 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

fev 07 16:48:19 raspberry systemd[1]: gerente.service: Unit entered failed state.
fev 07 16:48:19 raspberry systemd[1]: gerente.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
fev 07 16:48:20 raspberry systemd[1]: gerente.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
fev 07 16:48:20 raspberry systemd[1]: Stopped Gerente.
fev 07 16:48:20 raspberry systemd[1]: gerente.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
fev 07 16:48:20 raspberry systemd[1]: Failed to start Gerente.
fev 07 16:48:20 raspberry systemd[1]: gerente.service: Unit entered failed state.
fev 07 16:48:20 raspberry systemd[1]: gerente.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Utilize o *PM2*

Comment: Vou analisar o PM2, obrigado @ValdeirPsr.

Comment: Achei a solução boa, mas ao reiniciar o Raspberry, a aplicação não é iniciada automaticamente. Tem como configurar o PM2 para iniciar os processos no boot.

Comment: Verifiquei que tem como, estou analisando...

Comment: @ValdeirPsr consegui. Solução excelente, atende perfeitamente. Você pode responder para que eu marque a sua resposta como solução? Muito obrigado.